# How do I handle multiple Visual Studio configurations when doing continuous integration?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, continuous-integration

I have multiple configurations set up in Visual Studio so that I can build one solution (containing multiple projects) for one of a number of customers. A small number of web.config settings are customized depending on the customer, and the code is built to a different 'BuildDir' so I can package it up and deliver it. At the moment this is all driven from the Visual Studio Configuration Manager on my dev machine in conjunction with a couple of Web Deployment Projects, and I'm finding this pretty fragile.

I want to implement a CI server (CC.Net or TeamCity) but am not sure how to best accommodate this sort of per-client configuration (or if I should be attempting to). I develop in a branch, and reintegrate with the trunk as each feature is completed. Am I correct in thinking then that the CI server should be integrating the code in trunk, and if so, how do I deal with debug and release builds for each customer?

My configurations are:

- Development (debug)
- Test (debug)
- UAT - Cust. 1 (release)
- Production - Cust. 1 (release)
- UAT - Cust. 2 (release)
- Production - Cust. 2 (release)
- etc.

Apart from the small number of configuration settings for each customer the product is pretty much the same for all of them.

I'm keen to get your thoughts on how I could set this up, or whether I'm thinking about this wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by integrating the code in trunk? I think that builds for customers must be built in release only. They want to see only the product - not the details of unhandled exception. If you want to have debug builds with new feature in branch then make two different checkouts of your repository. First one is trunk only - for customers, second one will be located to your branch and build the product with the feature you are working on. I don't think that customers will want to see partially working buggy feature.

Comment: I agree with you - maybe my explanation wasn't very clear. My customers only see Release builds. I generate a Debug build locally for Dev, and a Debug build for Test (with different connection strings, etc.) I do feature dev in a branch, and reintegrate into trunk when done. Because the software is the same for all customers, I was thinking I'd use CI on the code in trunk and then 'it' (CI, or something else) could sort out the web.configs and then drop and package code for my different customers. This sounds like @andriy-k's suggestion below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using [UppercuT](http://code.google.com/p/uppercut/), [RoundHousE](http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/) and CC.Net, and by changing the way I branch and tag the various configurations in SVN. Now I have one 'mainline' of code (the trunk) that is automatically built by CC.Net/UppercuT on the build server and is then made available for packaging and deployment using UppercuT. If I need to build a specific customer's source, I can get their source,  make the necessary change, and then commit back to their branch. Running UppercuT within that branch then produces a deployable package for that customer. The combination of UppercuT and NAnt provides much greater flexibility IMO that using VS2010's Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 1):

We adhered two-step building procedure: first solution is build normally with Debug/Release configuration. Next (after build completion procedure), task is run for transforming web.configs(this if for one file, but it can be easily fixed to handle bunch of them):

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>
<Target Name="TransformWebConfig">
    <TransformXml Source="$(WebFolderName)Web.config"
        Transform="$(WebConfigsFolderName)Web.$(WebConfiguration).config"
        Destination="$(WebFolderName)Web.config" />
</Target>
```

This way
1) You have only two meaningful configurations in solution file
2) On build server you're passing two properties: Configuration (e.g. Release) and WebConfiguration (e.g. UATCust2)
3) This task is only run on build server, as it is part of bigger build script: developers are always working with default Debug/Release configuration, target platform configurations can be stored separately, e.g. in protected section in repository, or even on network share.